# Unable to delete files from Samba folder

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, samba

I am using Samba as the file share system from a Raspberry Pi to my windows computer. The Raspberry pi is running a Flask Web Server that intakes 3d print files that people upload and saves them in certain file structure that I have access to with Samba. On the windows side I can create and delete any file I want but I cannot delete files/folders that the python script makes. The error on the windows side is that I require permission from **Unix User\root**.  Here is the config for Samba.

```
[share]
Path = /home/***/Documents/3D Print Files
comment = 3D_Print_File_Server
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
valid users = root
force group = root
public = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

I am not sure why I cannot delete files because I am forcing the group to be root. Let me know what you all think.

Thanks!

-Noah